# handle this datatype whith reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I don't know how to handle this datatype.

```
object wert = x.GetValue(instanz);

List<object> element = new List<object>();

if (wert.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(t => t == typeof(IEnumerable)))
{                           
    foreach (var item in wert as IEnumerable)
    {    
     //this works for Lists, but not for the Datatype i have here(see link in my post)  
     //I get "null" for "y.GetValue(item)"       
     element.Add(item.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.GetValue(item)));
    }
}
```

Immediate window:

```
wert as IEnumerable
```

Will return:

```
Count = 1
    [0]: "51000"
```

Here you can find deeper informations: [click](https://pasteboard.co/GGckLFN.png)

For the `y` in the `foreach` will fail when it hits `y.GetValue(item)`: [click](https://pasteboard.co/GGcD68A.png)

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: mmh, what could be the solution ...

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Show the information needed in your text, not as images. Explain your type better (I see nothing referring to it in your links).